# Compress-7zip in powershell sometimes creates invalid zip file

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I installed the 7zip powershell components to compress large VM exports.  I'm using powershell commands to export a VM, rename it with a date, compress it with 7zip with a .zip extension then remove the original export.  These commands have worked consistently for months on all my exports.  I now get an intermittent error stating "The Compressed (zipped) Folder '\servername\d$\VM_Exports\oracledev_20200227.zip' is invalid."  This occurs on 2 oracle VMs on 2 different servers.  All other oracle exports work fine.  All other VM exports work fine.

My simple commands are:

```
$VMOracleName = 'oracledev'

$VMExportPath = 'D:\VM_Exports'

$Date = (Get-Date).toString('yyyyMMdd')

Export-VM -Name $VMOracleName -Path $VMExportPath

Rename-Item -Path "D:\VM_Exports\oracledev" -NewName "D:\VM_Exports\oracledev_$Date"

Compress-7Zip -Path D:\VM_Exports\oracledev_$Date -ArchiveFileName D:\VM_Exports\oracledev_$Date.zip

Remove-Item -Path D:\VM_Exports\oracledev_$Date -Recurse -Force
```

The files with invalid errors seem like they compressed correctly as there is a smaller file size but I cannot open the file.  I am inexperienced with powershell.  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have 7-Zip installed, then it would seem you don't need `Compress-7Zip` (whatever that is) at all. Just run `7z.exe` with whatever parameters you want.

Comment: We don't have 7-zip on the server.  I was trying to learn more about powershell and discovered the 7zip powershell components allowed me to compress very large files so I went with it.  I created a scheduled task to run and modeled from another script until I can get better at this.  I did learn that using the 7zip utility that I can see the contents of the file so at least I know I can use them for restore if I have to.  I just can't understand why File Explorer has issues seeing some of the compressed files and not others.  I finally decided to ask for help.  Thanks for responding.